# Multi gesture recognizer on one view

Tags: ios, swift

My working code slides a label of to the left of the window and slide it again to the right to show it fully. Since I am learning swift, I would appreciate your comments to improve on it. I included some factoring which failed to work.

Working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
var swipGestureRight: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!
var swipGestureLeft: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true

    swipGestureLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipViewLeft:"))
    swipGestureLeft.direction = .Left
    parentView.gestureRecognizers = [swipGestureLeft]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func swipViewLeft(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {self.myLabel.center.x -= (self.myLabel.bounds.width)}, completion: nil)
    swipGestureRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipViewRight:"))
    swipGestureRight.direction = .Right
    parentView.gestureRecognizers = [swipGestureRight]
}

func swipViewRight(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {self.myLabel.center.x += (self.myLabel.bounds.width)}, completion: nil)
    swipGestureLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipViewLeft:"))
    swipGestureLeft.direction = .Left
    parentView.gestureRecognizers = [swipGestureLeft]
}
}
```

Failed after trying to improve:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
var swipGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true

    swipGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipping:"))

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func swipping(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.direction == .Left {
        parentView.gestureRecognizers = [gestureRecognizer]
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {self.myLabel.center.x -= (self.myLabel.bounds.width)}, completion: nil)
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {self.myLabel.center.x += (self.myLabel.bounds.width)}, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about move

```
parentView.gestureRecognizers = [gestureRecognizer]
```

to `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: if I move it to be the last line in viewDidLoad(), the left swipe does not fire which must be done first as I am trying to mimic a slide nav bar ;)